# SmartGWT RestDateSource and Paging (Large DataSet of) Dynamic Data

Tags: java, rest, gwt, jdbc, smartgwt

I have a database table for log messages and at any time there can be inserted new rows. I want to show them in grid and when you scroll down I want to request more rows form this table (server side) but without to be affected from new added rows. The new rows only have to be visible if I refresh the whole grid.

I'm not sure how can I request rows in a range (from, to) using JDBC. I think there is no portable (across deferent databases) SQL query to do this? (I'm using MYSQL)

I think that after reading first page of this table I have to send to the client side the Max Id from log table and after that request new rows using this Max Id as parameter in SQL (WHERE id <= MAXID) but I'm not sure how I can pass this parameter from server to client and back using RestDateSource?

Do you have any better ideas how I can make this?

P.S. I'm using LGPL SmartGWT version and using my own servlets for server side.

Comment: I have another idea: I can find this MAXID from first page result (id of the first received row), but this will work only if I disable sorting in user interface which is not so bad idea. But how to send this parameter from client to server for another pages and how to request rows in range with JDBC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I would do; I imagine that you either have a growing-number ID or a timestamp for each of your rows.

Before you start querying for data, you call a webservice to query the current id (eg last line insterted is 12345).

Then you add a Criteria object to your datasource that says "rowId <= 12345". At this point, you can use the grid freely - paging, sorting, etc will work automatically as new rows will automatically be excluded.

(Or if you use a personalized datasource and not the default RESTdataSource, you basically do the same thing without using Criteria explicitly).

Comment: And by the way, how can I make "less or equal" crieteria?

Comment: I'd go for "rowId < (12345+1) "

Comment: See my comment on my answer below - the proposed strategy handles insertion but not deletion, and also does not handle updates to already-loaded records, which may also be a requirement.  A more complete implementation is to have a field that, when a record is added or updated, gets the current timestamp, then pass the timestamp of the earliest loaded records back and forth between client and server, invalidating cache when there's a mismatch.  We make this trivial in SmartGWT since there is a field type "modifierTimestamp" that does this automatically.

Answer (score 0):

SmartGWT Pro and better do this automatically.  Even if you don't want to use Pro, you can download the evaluation (smartclient.com/builds) and watch the server-side console, where the SQL queries are logged.

Comment: I saw that they are using LIMIT (SQL) but they still have the problem with newly concurent inserted rows. http://www.stackoverflow.com.s3.amazonaws.com/Concurent%20Insert.png

Comment: We provide a flag you can set on a response from the server to invalidate the current cache.  Determining when to invalidate the cache is something you do based on a strategy similar to the above (rowId) except of course that strategy doesn't handle deletion.  Since doing this requires you to have a sequence field or similar to track changes, we don't turn it on automatically.  But it's straightforward to add if you have the data available to do the detection.  Our server framework allows you to add Java logic which runs in addition to the automatic SQL operation for this kind of usage.